# Create a calculated column within a while loop in powerbi DAX

Tags: loops, powerbi, dax, measure

| Index | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 |
| 2 | Group1 |
| 3 | Group2 |
| 4 | Group2 |
| 5 | Group3 |
| 6 | Group3 |
| 7 | Group4 |
| 8 | Group4 |

Hello everyone,
I have to create a measure with a new column called 'Group'. Basically, I have to iterate over my index and then insert the value *GroupX*. This value change every 2 rows and I need to use a while loop which dynamically fix the dimension of my table.

For example I have to translate this IF Statement in a while loop DAX:

1. add an index column to your table called "index"
2. add a new column named "EXPORT_GROUP" to your table (in the example below change TblName to your actual table name) :

```
EXPORT_GROUP = switch (true(),
AND(TblName[Index]>=0, TblName[Index]<=20000), "Group1",
AND(TblName[Index]>=20001, TblName[Index]<=40000), "Group2",
"Group3")
```

I am not sure how to do this

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: a request for a project

Answer (score 0):

```
Group = "Group" &ROUNDUP(('Table'[Index])/2,0)
```

[image: solution]